# Why did people start using CO2 (instead of e.g. oxygen) for carbonated drinks?

Tags: drinks, carbonation

I am curious about why those who invented carbonated drinks chose to use specifically carbon dioxide in the liquid, instead of some other gas (say, oxygen).

(Obviously they wouldn't necessarily have been called "carbonated" if some other gas had been used, but that is besides the point.)

Is there some reason such as that CO2 does not dissipate from a liquid as fast as other gases, or something else?

Comment: cherry phosphate anyone?

Comment: I remember there being a story in Japan of *hydrogenated* beer allowing people to sing higher notes at Karaoke bars and igniting burps with lit cigarettes(!) Don't remember where I read it. Have to look around...

Comment: Oxygen was too lonely by itself so it had to get his buddy carbon to join the bubbly fun and now you got CO2 instead of just O

Comment: @JosephMurray that will be http://www.darwinawards.com/legends/legends1999-11.html

Comment: @DavidWallace - while amusing, that story is an [urban legend](http://www.snopes.com/humor/jokes/hydrogenbeer.asp)

Comment: Guiness is carbonated with nitrogen btw.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

CO<sub>2</sub> tastes good! Carbonated water is actually a weak carbonic acid solution; this is what you taste. It's like "salt and pepper", but for water.

Slightly acidic water is usually popular, hence lemon juice is sometimes used to taint a jug of water in times when no carbonated water is available.

Carbonated water releases CO<sub>2</sub> bubbles for many minutes after pressure is released (dissolved carbonic acid reforming), which is an important presentation effect that other gases do not generally have.

In many countries the local water supply is slightly alkaline (due to limestone rock being very common), and this can leave a bad after-taste, and make food in your mouth taste soapy. The addition of weak acids to water helps with neutralising this effect.

Around the world, some lucky towns have natural springs with effervescent water (carbonated water), and man-made carbonated water is just imitating this. In history people have often travelled great distances to try effervescent water, so its popularity is well recorded.

Nitrogen is used for water pressurisation in brewing and cooking as it leaves little or no taste, and generally does not form other chemical compounds. It's used mainly when bubbles are required, but not an acidic taste.

Oxygen is unsuitable for water pressurisation as very little can be dissolved at normal soda pressures, and it has no taste, but may readily form unwanted chemical compounds.

In the 18th century, Joseph Priestley was the first person to document this manufacturing discovery. He noted precisely that it tasted good, and that it was similar to the German Selters water. He was discovering "airs" (gases), and uniquely identified quite a few different gases. CO<sub>2</sub> was the only one he listed as tasting good. His cheap source of CO<sub>2</sub> was the fermenting grains from the nearby brewery.

Comment: Also, oxygen is quite a bit more dangerous to handle (probably not the main reason it is not used, but just in case someone wanted to try...)

Comment: Actually, most of the "taste" of carbonated water is the carbon dioxide setting off the pain receptors in your mouth. (Yay, masochism!)

Comment: O2 would also be a lot more expensive.

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted? It may be full of interesting facts but the question was "Why did people *start* using CO2 in drinks", and the correct answer (given below by David Powers) is that it was a by-product of fermentation. Before anyone says carbonated = non-alcoholic, ginger beer.

Comment: @PeterWone: David's answer is also incorrect in the sense you say this answer is incorrect - the answer is that it's because naturally bubbly mineral water are carbonated and people imitated what nature produced (as stated in this answer). A more complete answer is probably both. It's like saying Diamler invented cars while ignoring Benz.

Comment: @slebetman - you may be right. Fermentation is the how, not the why.

Comment: @David — Yep, the sparkling feeling in the mouth is nice. But don't the bubbles set off the *touch receptors* rather than the *pain receptors* ? By the way, are there such things as *pain receptors* ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Yes, there are [pain receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nociceptor) and here's an [article](http://dornsife.usc.edu/news/stories/796/sparkling-drinks-spark-pain-circuits/) about their relation to carbonated drinks.

Comment: @TFD - didn't you notice that I already conceded this to slebetman?

Comment: Why cannot oxygen be dissolved as much as CO2 ?

Comment: Actually, there is Water with O2 sold here: http://www.activeo2.de/. Many people do question the effect though, but they claim it is healthier and helps in sports because of the O2.

Comment: Most things are invented by different people in different ways for different reasons.  There was already an answer about naturally carbonated mineral water (which in my experience is insufficiently carbonated and too hard - too adulterated with Calcium and often other minerals for my taste), and in some places where such springs occur this may have been a factor. But the documented route is via brewing with CO2 derived from brewing/yeast. Things going off due to yeast or bacterial contamination is common, and people had to develop a taste for beer, wine, vinegar, leavened bread, yoghurt, etc.

Comment: Actually people also infuse/activate water with O3 - ozone.

Comment: Actually CO2 is toxic in large quantities, that is when it is too high a proportion of the air we are breathing, and so we react strongly to CO2 concentration detected as a noxious substance - in low concentrations noxious substances can be stimulating even medicinal, in that they stimulate positive reactions in the body. The same applies to acidity in general where a small amount in food/drink can be positive, but imbibing/consuming/touching concentrated acid is very dangerous.

Answer (score 34):

Brewing processes often introduce carbon dioxide naturally, usually along with alcohol.

Carbonated beverages get the fizz and some spiciness/acidity without the alcohol.

Comment: I think this is the real answer. Slightly fermented drinks were popular before industrial carbonation. Taste is not the reason why people started using CO2, but why they continued it. And it is an acquired taste. But many already had acquired it before there were chemically carbonated sodas.

Answer (score 27):

Oxygen is MUCH less soluble in water than carbon dioxide.  This is due to formation of carbonic acid. There would certainly be much less "fizz" if soda was charged with oxygen under the same conditions of pressure and temperature.

Also it might be undesirable to have high oxygen concentration in the sealed drink as this might reduce shelf life. In certain ways carbon dioxide can act as a preservative.

All answers posted so far sound good.

Comment: Bottles pumped full of oxygen would also be a major fire hazard.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Drunks would no doubt have great fun dropping lit cigarettes into such bottles. Instant fireworks!

Comment: Water normally has dissolved oxygen. Adding more (still less than 1%, as in carbonation) isn't going to make any difference

Comment: @TFD Ordinary water has some dissolved gas but not very much. From what I can see on the internet, the amount of CO2 in Coke is about one to three times the volume of the liquid, which is a much greater amount. One distributor I found was offering Coke on pallets of 108 cases, each case holding 24 330ml cans. That's 864 litres of Coke, which would be between 900 and 2700 litres of oxygen (0.9 to 2.7 cubic metres). That is not an insignificant amount of oxygen.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's not that simple. Read up on Henry's Law re. dissolved gasses. Also, CO2 does not just dissolve, it forms a chemical compound (carbonic acid), hence you can get grams per litre, with oxygen you are only ever going to get mg per litre

Comment: The best answer.  The first sentence says it all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Why would oxygen be a fire hazard? It's not like it explodes when you light it on fire...

Comment: @Mehrdad Because it makes fires burn more vigorously and, in high enough concentration, it can make things spontaneously combust.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Interesting, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

An interesting addition to the answers above: There's such thing as *nitrogenation*, where nitrogen is used along with CO2. This is done mostly to replicate the flavor of beer with *less* carbonation, which is common in places such as England where beer is served at 55F. CO2 becomes less able to dissolve with temperature increase, therefore higher temperatures mean less carbonation. Many beer drinkers say that carbonation makes flavors harsher, whereas nitrogenation replicates "traditional" beers where the carbonation affects the taste less. It also has effects on mouth feel and appearance.

> A nitro beer will taste a bit flatter, but will make up for that with a full, creamy mouthfeel.

source: [Beer On Nitro - A Brewer's Explanation](http://www.lbbrew.com/beer-on-nitro/)

CO2 isn't the only thing used to add effervescence to beverages. It's just the most common.

Comment: As anyone who's ever drunk Beer or any other draft drink fro ma English pub will tell you; There is no standard serving temperature, in fact it's highly likely that some places go out of their way to warm the stuff up!!! ;-)

Answer (score 8):

To be a little more historical (why people *started* using CO2), I'll say that bubbly beverages all originated from fermentation. Even things that we have as non-alcoholic beverages - root beer, ginger beer, used to be fermented a bit (and still are, by people that make their own.)

The flavors that we have come to enjoy were developed in the context carbonic acid, especially the sweetness. And as others have pointed out, oxygen is bad for flavors. Beer in particular is affected by oxygen, the yeast will generate sour/cidery flavors in the presence of oxygen and other stale flavors appear.

Side note: artificial addition of nitrogen to beer is a recent thing meant to mimic traditional cask ale, where carbonation is low and air is forced into the cask to push the beer out. In the short time before the oxygen damages the beer, the nitrogen will dissolve in the beer giving smaller bubbles and creamier foam.

Comment: Natural soda springs occur all around the worlds. Surely people  would have drank those long before bottled fermentation was achieved

Comment: True, and I have tasted some of that water direct from the source. It often contains SO2 or H2S, yet that has not caught on yet (luckily).

Answer (score 6):

Man tends to follow nature.

Water passing through limestone ( CaCO3 )
dissolves a tiny amount of the limestone
and flavors the water.

If that water is artesian, it can have more
dissolved Limestone, but as the water 
exits the ground, into a condition of
lower pressure, the dissolved CO2
is released ( forms bubbles ).

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers is actually quite right (though some come close). First, it has nothing to do with simulating natural fermentation products or naturally occurring liquids. Nor does it have anything to do with safety in transport.
Nor does it have much to do with taste (especially since, as others have already pointed out, the sensation of soda has very little to do with taste, and much more to do with stimulating nociceptors in the mouth).
CO2 is used because it is one of the only non-toxic, easily and cheaply producible gases that can remain dissolved in significant concentrations in water.
while about 1.75g of CO2 can be dissolved in a kilogram of water at room temperature, only about 0.02g of nitrogen can dissolve in the same amount of water. The situation is not significantly better for oxygen, where only about 0.04g per kilogram of water will stay in solution.

Comment: There was actually one older answer (http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/52218/1672) that does mention solubility, but your answer (especially the numbers, showing the two order of magnitude difference) is really helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

I would think the Oxygen would chemically interact with
the sugars and other components of the soda, and in effect
burn the contents!

Comment: Water normally has dissolved oxygen. Adding more (still less than 1%, as in carbonation) isn't going to make any difference

Comment: @TFD The amount of gas dissolved in tap water is of the order of milligrams per litre, which is negligible; the amount of gas dissolved in soda is of the order of grams per litre, a hundred to a thousand times more. That's going to make a difference.

Comment: So do we know for sure if oxygenating drinks would create undesired chemical reactions?

Answer (score 3):

Adding my 2 cents:
Having constructed a coke bottling plant (not operated), I'm aware that tiny amounts of activate carbon is an ingredient and the reason given was that it would react with any dissolved oxygen thereby inhibiting bacterial growth in the sugared drink.

In fact, if you were to drink fresh coke from a bottling plant, it's a bit harsh on taste. This, I'm assuming here; is because the activated C in the drink initially forms concentrates of CO3 ions before it squeezes out the remaining O ions from the solvent to stabilize to dissolved and evenly spread CO2. I must admit, that I couldn't balance the equation here.

But I do know that if you mix coke with say a bacterial fermenting item like say yogurt or beer; cap it and rock it; it could result in a small and sudden explosion. The trick to bottling coke lays in carbonating it before any bacterial formation could take place.

Comment: What bacteria grows in a liquid that is as acidic as vinegar?

Answer (score -3):

As a wrestler in highschool I of course was restricted from drinking carbonated beverages furring season,. This is what first made me question why CO2 not O2? When I presented the dilemma to my ex-husband NASA science teacher (who by the way might have been a bit fried from the 70's...) Told me " well instead of a borring explanation how bout I give a demonstration" so as a crude representation of one of the possible issue he opened a soda, shook it until it was flat the poured some in a test tube. Now in the same tube he had a glass pipet inserted and started pumping pure O2 into it. As I watched it bubleing and such I was thinking to my self, "what the hell does this prove?"  But then he took a torch and lit the oxygen rich liquid sugar syrup that is soda and showed just how violently a powerful hydrocarbon, like monosaccharide, reacts in the presence of extra oxygen... So in summary, flavor and texture aside, it's just impractical to have huge factories producing pressurized oxidized hydrocarbons for the enjoyment lil kids at the supermarket!

Comment: I hope that was helpful,  after reading all the info and data in the previous posts I decided I had to tell that story. :)

Comment: Flammability has nothing to do with why carbon dioxide is used instead of oxygen.